# NSDate from NSString returning null problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Here is my string stored in the value below: 2011-03-13 23:22:05

Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter dateFromString: [dict valueForKey:@"Message"]];
[m setLastSyncDate:[formatter dateFromString: [dict valueForKey:@"Message"]]];
NSLog(@"New LastSyncDate: %@ : %@",[dict valueForKey:@"Message"], m.LastSyncDate);
```

This is the response I get in console:

```
New LastSyncDate: 2011-03-13 23:22:05 : (null)
```

Why am I getting a (null) here?

UPDATE CODE:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
            Manufacturer *m = [self.manufacturers objectAtIndex:i];
            [m setLastSyncDate:[formatter dateFromString: [dict valueForKey:@"Message"]]];
            NSLog(@"New LastSyncDate: %@ : %@",[formatter dateFromString: [dict valueForKey:@"Message"]], m.LastSyncDate);
```

RETURNS:

```
New LastSyncDate: (null) : (null)
```

Comment: hh should be HH because you are using 24 hour format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

updated code:

```
 NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];


    //2011-03-13 23:22:05
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]; ///add this line


    NSString* message;
    NSDate* LastSyncDate;

    message=@"2011-03-13 23:22:05";
    LastSyncDate=[formatter dateFromString:message];

    NSLog(@"New LastSyncDate: %@ : %@",message, LastSyncDate);
```

Comment: once I cast my dic valueForKey to NSString things worked - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [set the date format string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBEDIHH).

---

You also need to make sure that `[dict valueForKey:@"Message"]` isn't returning `nil`.